# How can i read read a textfile and write it to a datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, text-files

How can i write from a textfile to a datagrid

with the following code i write to a textfile from a datagrid

```
string file_name = "text.txt";
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < datagrid.Items.Count; i++)
        {

            //this is the class person
            Person prsn = (Person) datagrid.Items[i];
            strBuilder.Append(prsn.ToString());
        }
        File.WriteAllText(file_name, strBuilder.ToString());
```

My text file looks like this

5/30/2017 12:00:00 AM:10:00:Tom:Boy|5/30/2017 12:00:00 AM:10:00:KElly:Girl|

and my methode to read it from the textfile to datagrid looks like this

```
    public void todatagrid()
    {
        string textfile = "text.txt";

        List<string> textvalues = File.ReadAllLines(textfile).ToList();
        datagrid.ItemsSource = textvalues.ToList();

    }
```

but when i do this and load the form my datagrid shows the following value

count
148

how can i read it in a prober way and post it in a datagrid and not datagridview

Comment: Show us Datagrid bindings, Person class, Where are you using "todatagrid" method.

Comment: @NareshRavlani to read the textfile and write it to datagrid

Comment: Your posted question lacks too much information. We can't help you without knowing your implementation. Please ask a precise question and provide sufficient information.

Comment: You are saving Person type objects to the file (Obviously they are stored in your DataGrid.) and then trying to add string values to DataGrid. Use Serialization instead. Serialize your Person objects list, and then deserialize the file to Person objects list.

Comment: Or you could write a method List<Person> GetPersons(IEnumerable<string> textvalues) and then call it datagrid.ItemsSource = GetPersons(textvalues);

Comment: Saving complex objects to `Text` is never a good option. As Yevgeniy pointed out `Serialization` is your way to go. I recommend `JSON` or `XML`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

That's because DataGrid looks for properties of containing objects. You have to do something like below:
**Update:**

```
    public void todatagrid()
    {
        List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();

        string textfile = "test.txt";

        var textvalues = File.ReadAllLines(textfile);

        foreach (var item in textvalues)
        {
            persons.Add(new Person() { Value = item });
        }
        datagrid.ItemsSource = persons;    
    }

    class Person
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }   //Whatever this field is
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Saving complex objects to `Text` is not a good option.
Reading Text and parse it back to the object is a lot of work (for you and the CPU). You would have to split your Lines into the properties of your object, create a new instance of person and set the values for each property.

**Don't make it that hard for you.**

You should use `Serialization` instad.

An easy example woud be sth like this:

1. Create your Object List ( `List<Persons>` )
2. Show them in your DataGrid
3. Add/Remove or do what ever u want with it
4. Take the Contents of the DataGrids,  serialize it and store it as JSON using [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)
5. On Application_Start reload and deserialize your file into `List<Person>`
6. Rebind you List to your GridView's ItemsSource

Alternatively you could do the same using any `XmlSerializer`